# Multi cloud provider kubernetes cluster pod logs got timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubeadm, kubectl

Hi all i have master node in digital ocean and worker node in google cloud, nodes are connected using public ip of master node[image] and pods are in running status but when i run kubectl logs i'm getting timeout error , also i noticed log is calling with local ip so there is no host in it , any one help on this ? is there any possible way to call logs using public ip ?

Update: adding /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
annotations:
kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 104.248.40.128:6443
creationTimestamp: null
labels:
component: kube-apiserver
tier: control-plane
name: kube-apiserver
namespace: kube-system
spec:
containers:

- command:

  - kube-apiserver
  - --advertise-address=104.248.40.128
  - --allow-privileged=true
  - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
  - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
  - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
  - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
  - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
  - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
  - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
  - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
  - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
  - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
  - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
  - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
  - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
  - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
  - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
  - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
  - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
  - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
  - --secure-port=6443
  - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
  - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
  - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
  - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
- --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt

  - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.26.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 8
    httpGet:
    host: 104.248.40.128
    path: /livez
    port: 6443
    scheme: HTTPS
    initialDelaySeconds: 10
    periodSeconds: 10
    timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 3
    httpGet:
    host: 104.248.40.128
    path: /readyz
    port: 6443
    scheme: HTTPS
    periodSeconds: 1
    timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
    requests:
    cpu: 250m
    startupProbe:
    failureThreshold: 24
    httpGet:
    host: 104.248.40.128
    path: /livez
    port: 6443
    scheme: HTTPS
    initialDelaySeconds: 10
    periodSeconds: 10
    timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
    name: ca-certs
    readOnly: true
  - mountPath: /etc/pki
    name: etc-pki
    readOnly: true
  - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
    name: k8s-certs
    readOnly: true
    hostNetwork: true
    priorityClassName: system-node-critical
    securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
    type: RuntimeDefault
    volumes:
  - hostPath:
    path: /etc/ssl/certs
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
    path: /etc/pki
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
    path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
    status: {}

kubectl get endpoints gives below
NAME                       ENDPOINTS                         AGE
kubernetes                 104.248.40.128:6443               34h
webserver-simple-service   10.244.1.7:8000,10.244.1.8:8000   33h

Comment: `Thom` can you check whether your public IP got reflected in your config, the following command will help you in finding that **kubectl config view** . If your kube-api-endpoint is pointing to your internal IP you can follow this [blog](https://ystatit.medium.com/deploy-kubernetes-with-specific-public-ip-address-for-control-plane-endpoint-cef1a54b2fbf) written by **Yst@IT** for changing your kube-api-endpoint to public IP.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni i have checked kubectl config view the server: https://104.248.40.128:6443 it's a public ip and api is working in browser also , but only thing i noticed it's not have valid ssl certificate dose it make problem ?

Comment: have you used SSL certificate while creating the kubernetes cluster..? If so then it might cause issues, so you need to use a valid SSL either it might be a self signed one or OpenSSL based one or from some other third party.

Comment: also can you provide steps or document that you are following so that we can try to replicate the issue and provide a better solution.

Comment: i have followed this article https://dev.to/kcdchennai/create-a-multi-cloud-setup-of-kubernetes-cluster-936

Comment: can you try querying the logs by passing the endpoint parameter..?
kubectl logs <pod_name> --endpoint=http://104.248.40.128:6443 or change port number to 10250

Comment: it says error: unknown flag: --endpoint

Comment: can you provide what is available in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and also the output of **kubectl get endpoints** command

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni i have updated the yaml and endpoint details in the question , kindly check it

Comment: all the kubernetes looks fine can you check the firewall rules for this public IP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144994/discussion-between-kranthiveer-dontineni-and-thom).